# How to sort each row of a Google Sheet in Alphabetical Order

Tags: google-apps-script

Say I have a range, "A3:C5" such that:

3. Bob, Cob, Rob
4. Joe, Foe, Boe
5. Jack, Back, Sack

and I want this reformatted in the Google sheet to be

3. Bob, Cob, Rob
4. Boe, Foe, Joe
5. Back, Jack, Sack

In other words, I want the data to be sorted only in the rows they are in by alphabetical order. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this in google apps script, would anyone be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

Quick google search:

[Tested and it works](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/KzxSGNFvQJo/s3fxR7s6_sAJ)

```
function sortHorizontal()
{

  var startCol = 1;              // left-most column to where the sort will be applied; A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 etc
  var startRow = 1;              // first row to apply the sort
  var sheetName = 'Sheet1';      // name of sheet in which sort will be applied

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var d = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  var output = [], temp;
  for (var i = startRow - 1; i < d.length; i++)
  {
    temp = d[i].slice(startCol - 1);
    temp.sort(ascSort);          // change to descSort for Z -> A sort
    output.push(temp);
  }
  s.getRange(startRow, startCol, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}


function ascSort(a, b)
{
  return ((a == b) ? 0 : (a && (!b || a < b)) ? -1 : 1);
}


function descSort(a, b)
{
  return ((a == b) ? 0 : (a > b) ? -1 : 1);
}
```